# Using an OV7670, Arduino Uno, ESP8266 and SD card

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, sd-card

I am planning to create a project which will take a picture with OV7670 and `Arduino Uno` with `SD card` and send it to server with `ESP8266`.

is it possible to use Arduino Uno(it has only 2k RAM memory)?

Comment: you now you can buy an IP camera?

Comment: I think if you want to save and deploy more than just simple still images in rather big time distances you won't get lucky with the Uno. All the data would have to go through the Uno, which is not a trivial task. Though it may be possible, you should consider using a more capable board.

Comment: And why do you want to use the Uno? The ESP is way more powerful (it's not just the wifi functionality)